# Flex 3 and flash player caching

Tags: flash, caching, apache-flex

I pass text strings from a configuration file into my Flex app, one of the strings I pass in is a mailto link which I use to allow users of my app to send me feedback. I recently needed to change this link however when I updated the link in my config file the change did not happen instantly in my Flex app.

In fact, I had to clear my cache (both browser and flash player) before the change showed up. This of course is fine for me but how can I be sure that users of the application also get the updated content? Is there a way to force a refresh of data loaded into my swf on other users browsers?

Finally is this an issue with my browser cache or the Flash player cache? Does the flash player only keep such data, like my email address, in memory while the app is in use and then clear once it is closed or does it cache this data for the next time the user wants to use the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to your browser cache, and it happens with all the resources, not only for Flash movies. There are several ways to prevent that:

a)Set the headers for the HTML document as is described [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/147/tn_14743.html).

b)Use a mechanism to control the caching. Append a token to your resource (like my.html?id=12) and change this token when the swf is changed. In this way you will benefit from the caching mechanism and in the same time you are going to have control over it.